# Is it possible if $M$ goes up and $m$ comes down?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, string

Masses M and m are connected to a system of strings and pulleys as shown in the diagram.The strings are massless and inextensible, and the pulleys are massless and frictionless. The cross hatched horizontal
beams are fixed in place.Is there any kind of setting where mass M would move up and mass m decend considering that the system is in static situation (i.e., when the two masses are in equilibrium with neither M nor m moving).

[image]

Comment: just increase the mass of m

Comment: Are you sure this is what you want to ask. If neither M nor m are moving then obviously M is not moving up and m is not descending.

Comment: They are moving, sorry for my wordings

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because homework-like questions should include an attempt at a solution.

Comment: If M equals 2 times m then they are  at equilibrium.

Comment: @ThePhoton - He isn't asking us to solve it. He is asking if the system can move, even if the weights are chosen so the system is balanced.

Comment: @mmesser314 in that case I vote to close because "yes" isn't a very interesting answer.

Comment: I think the point of the question is that the masses do not have to be at rest to be in equilibrium.

Comment: @ThePhoton But “yes, because ...” can be a very interesting and instructive answer. Surely you are not suggesting that every question that *could* be just answered yes/no should be closed ??

Comment: @gandalf61, in this case I don't see how to say much more than "yes" without doing the OP's homework for them. So if you want to answer "yes,  because..." then I vote to close because it's a homework question without an attempted solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If M is an elephant and m is a mouse, M will accelerate downward, pulling m up.

If M is a mouse and m is an elephant, m will accelerate downward, pulling M up.

Somewhere in between, the there is a balance where neither mass accelerates up or down. If the system is at rest, it will stay at rest. If you pull on a weight to start it moving, it will keep on moving.

Answer (score 2):

If the system is in equilibrium then the forces on both masses and on the lower pulley must net to zero. By considering the forces on each of the three objects you can derive three equations which must be met for equilibrium to exist.

But if the values of $m$ and $M$ are known then you only have two unknowns - the tensions in the two ropes. You can eliminate these two unknowns from the three equations and derive a relationship between $m$ and $M$ that must be satisfied in equilibrium.

Note, however, that the system can be in equilibrium *even if* the masses are not stationary. The equilibrium condition only means that they are not accelerating. The masses could both be moving with a constant velocity and still be in equilibrium - the term *mechanical equilibrium* is sometimes used to avoid the word static. If the masses are both moving with a constant velocity then by considering the geometry of the strings you can derive a relationship between their velocities.